# What is the prerequisit to studying spectral graph theory and hyper graphs? If one knows only the basics of graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, tensors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, hypergraphs

Can anyone suggest to me some books to learn spectral graph theory, hyper graph theory, and tensors used to study hyper graphs please? Preferribly books for beginners and then some books for advanced learning.

Answer (score 0):

As a prerequisite to Spectral Graph Theory, you should take a look at the more general Algebraic Graph Theory first and have a solid foundation of Linear Algebra. A book I used is Biggs, N. (1993) ‘Algebraic Graph Theory’ (2nd Ed.). UK: Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 0):

Spectral Graph Theory -
Fan R. K. Chung: University of Pennsylvania, Philadelphia, PA

this book is based on 10 lectures given at the CBMS workshop on spectral graph theory in June 1994. It present an introduction with all the prerequisites and it's very explicative for students with a knowledge in graph theory and linear algebra.

Answer (score -1):

Below are the books which I think are very useful in learning Algebraic Graph Theory especially the first one (As I learnt a lot form it ).
1. An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spectra Dragoš M. Cvetković, Peter Rowlinson, Slobodan Simić-  -Cambridge University Press (2010).

2. Introduction to Graph and Hypergraph Theory  Vitaly I. Voloshin